# Can a key combination change the look and content of a webpage after a page is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I think I can do it with javascript by manipulating the DOM but I get lost in the complexity. Can someone point me in the right direction?

I want to place a hidden site in a site. So the public never knows the difference unless they know the key combination that changes everything which toggles back the next time you hit the combo

Anyone ever hear of this and if so can you forward me a link so I can study up on it. Thank you... Searched for awhile but couldn't find anything...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to achieve this effect would be to write two pages directly on top of each other but only have one showing at a time like so:

```
<body>
    <div id="page1">
        ...content...
    </div>
    <div id="page2" style="display:none">
        ...content...
    </div>
</body>
```

Then use javascript to hide the first page and display the second on keypress.